# fix display of mailchip newsletter signup form on my website

Tags: inline

I have added a newsletter subscription box to my website, however it is not displaying properly. I would like to have the subscribe button displayed next to the box where you enter the email. I have added the following css:

```
#mc_embed_signup_scroll, #mc-submit {
    display:inline-block;   
}
```

However its not working.

http://www.skinmade.com.au/ (see footer)

Thanks in advance :)

Claire

Comment: would you mind posting the relevant bits of html and css in the question or on a fiddle site so we don't have to dig through your entire page to find it?

Comment: whoops sorry... i am using big cartel.... 

I have put the relevant code in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pfwfsq2z/

Answer (score 0):

The inputs themselves are styled `display:block` by the mail chimp css, which prevents them being rendered in the same line.  Also the `mc_embed_signup_scroll` div that contains them doesn't have a set width, so if its auto-width isn't wide enough for the inputs to appear side by side, the button will wrap to the next line.

To get them on the same line, override the display setting of the input elements, and set a minimum width on the containing div to make sure they fit on one line:

```
#mc_embed_signup input.email,
#mc_embed_signup input.button {
    display: inline !important;
}
#mc_embed_signup_scroll{
    min-width: 350px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pfwfsq2z/1/